# Efficient element-wise function computation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization

I have the following optimization problem. Given two np.arrays `X`,`Y` and a function `K` I would like to compute as fast as possible the matrix incidence gram_matrix where the `(i,j)-th` element is computed as `K(X[i],Y[j])`.

Here there an implementation using nested for-loops, which are acknowledged to be the slowest to solve these kind of problems.

```
def proxy_kernel(X,Y,K):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        for j, y in enumerate(Y):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K(x, y)
    return gram_matrix
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Might be good to ask this on Code Review instead.

Comment: Without any knowledge of what `K` is, you're not going to do much better than nested loops.

Comment: Unfortunately K is passed as parameter. It's sad, because it's really slow this implementation, but so far is the only one that works.

Comment: This is a basic `numpy` how-to question; it will get more answers here than on Code Review.

Comment: This has been asked before a number of times.  As long as `K` is a black-box that only takes scalars there isn't much you can do to improve the speed.  But for a start, compare the times for a typical `K` with times for the simplest possible `K`.  How much time is spent in iteration, and how time in evaluating `K` a zillion times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.vectorize` does make some improvement in speed - about 2x  (here I'm using `math.atan2` as an black box function that takes 2 scalar arguments).

```
In [486]: X=np.linspace(0,1,100)
In [487]: K_vect=np.vectorize(math.atan2)

In [488]: timeit proxy_kernel(X,X,math.atan2)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.84 ms per loop

In [489]: timeit K_vect(X[:,None],X)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

In [502]: timeit np.arctan2(X[:,None],X)  # numpy compiled loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 871 µs per loop
```

where

```
def proxy_kernel(X,Y,K):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
            for j, y in enumerate(Y):
                    gram_matrix[i, j] = K(x, y)
    return gram_matrix
```

As long as `K` is a black box, you are limited by the time it takes to invoke `K` the `X.shape[0]*Y.shape[0]` times.  You can try to minimize the iteration time, but you are still limited by all those function calls.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733040/901925 speeds up the calculation with a Gausian kernel, by taking advantage of the `axis` parameter of the `np.linalg.norm` function.

Comment: Given the name `gram_matrix`, I'm pretty sure `K` is supposed to be a function of two vectors, not two scalars.

Comment: On CR he references machine learning kernel functions; But he's still unclear about the dimensions; http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90005/efficient-element-wise-function-computation-in-python

Comment: Why does using vectorize give any speedup? I thought vectorize just makes the code prettier but is still just a for loop internally?

Comment: I don't know in this case.  `vectorize` uses `frompyfunc`.  `frompyfunc` often tests 2x faster than an explicit loop, but `vectorize` has more overhead and often is a bit slower.  But I don't dwell too much on 2x differences eitherway.  What we want at the 10x differences that `np.arctan2` provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely at least vectorize the inner loop:

```
def proxy_kernel_vect(X, Y, K):
    K_vect = np.vectorize(K)
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        gram_matrix[i] = K_vect(x, Y)
    return gram_matrix
```

This yields a nice improvement with relatively long arrays:

```
In [15]: a = np.array(range(1000))
    ...: b = np.array(range(1000))
    ...: 

In [16]: %timeit proxy_kernel(a, b, k)
1 loops, best of 3: 665 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit proxy_kernel_vect(a, b, k)
1 loops, best of 3: 266 ms per loop
```

where `k` is just `lambda x, y: x+y`.

Comment: What's your `k` here? I don't think applying `vectorize` this way actually preserves the original semantics.

Comment: @user2357112 It's defined in the last line of the answer. It's just a scalar function (since this is what the OP seems to use).

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to be a scalar function. In the usual definition of "Gram matrix", the function is an inner product.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't work in my code  `gram_matrix[i] = vect(x, Y) ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (600,2) into shape (600)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `vectorize` decorator from [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/ufuncs.html) module.

You particular problem is easily solved using `vectorize` and numpy [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)'])
def K(x,y):
    return x + y

a = np.arange(1000)
b = np.arange(1000)

gram_array = K(a[None,:], b[:, None])
```