# Generate a Gaussian kernel given mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731726/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-matrix-efficiently-in-numpy) question here addresses how to generate a Gaussian kernel using numpy. However I do not understand what the inputs used `kernlen` and `nsig` are and how they relate to the mean/standard deviation usually used to describe a Gaussian distribtion.

How would I generate a 2d Gaussian kernel described by, say `mean = (8, 10)` and `sigma = 3`? The ideal output would be a 2-dimensional array representing the Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `astropy`, especially the [`Gaussian2D`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian2D.html#astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian2D) model from the [`astropy.modeling.models`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/#id2) module:

```
from astropy.modeling.models import Gaussian2D

g2d = Gaussian2D(x_mean=8, y_mean=10, x_stddev=3, y_stddev=3)  # specify properties

g2d(*np.mgrid[0:100, 0:100])  # specify the grid for the array
```

[image]