# Adding Gaussian kernels to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have just come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078840/generate-a-gaussian-kernel-given-mean-and-standard-deviation?noredirect=1&lq=1) question about generating a 2D Gaussian kernel from certain parameters. I do not understand what the `*np.mgrid` line is doing.

I want to create many of these kernels and use them to reconstruct an image. This would involve taking the kernels and adding them to an originally empty `numpy` array. Using the method in the accepted answer in the above question generating the kernels is very fast, but the `np.mgrid` part is very slow. Is there a way to add the kernels to an array without creating a new array every time (which is what I think `np.mgrid` is doing).

Comment: Sorry, I have attempted to clarify my question.

Comment: Which part of the code do you think is generating the kernels? Because it's the last line, not the `Gaussian2D(...)` - that's just storing information about _how to generate_ a kernel

Comment: As you can see I don't really know how its working.. thanks for the clarification

Comment: Then ask clarifying comments on the answer