# Gaussian heat map

Tags: python, heatmap

I'm trying to plot a Gaussian heat map peak, similar to the image, but when creating a normal random matrix, I'm not getting this sort of heat map.

[image]

Here's my code, the result is...

Any help is great!

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

xy = np.random.normal(loc=256, scale= 200, size = (512,512))
print(xy)
plt.imshow(xy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `plt.imshow(xy, cmap=jet)`

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731726/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-matrix-efficiently-in-numpy

Comment: This is for two Gaussian distributions, but you will be able to adapt it for one: [How to efficiently compute the heat map of two Gaussian distribution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945111/how-to-efficiently-compute-the-heat-map-of-two-gaussian-distribution-in-python)

Comment: BTW: [Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use matplotlib.pyplot instead.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab)

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.normal` doesn't work the way you think it does.
This function returns random samples from the normal distribution defined by the `loc` and `scale` parameters. Each sample is independent of each other and hence the image is just noise.

Basically when you define the `size` to be 512 X 512, you are basically asking for 512 * 512 = 262144 independent random samples from the normal distribution which are arranged in the form of a 512 X 512 array. It is essentially not different than sampling one random value from the normal distribution 262144 times and reshaping the results yourself.

What you essentially want to do is to create a circularly symmetric 2D array in which the centermost value is equal to or very close to the `loc` value you want and values get farther away from `loc` the away from center you go. Once you have such a distribution, you can define a normal distribution object using `scipy.stats.norm` with the same `loc` value and an appropriate `scale`. You can then use that normal distribution object to get the probability density (pdf) values for your circularly symmetric 2D array which will mimic the image you want.