# PSF (point spread function) for an image (2D)

Tags: python, image-processing, blur, deconvolution

I'm new in image analysis (with Python) and I would like to apply the richardson_lucy deconvolution (from skimage) on my data (CT scans). For this reason, I estimated the PSF in "number of voxels" by means of a specific software. Its value is roughly 6.73 voxels, but I don't know how to use it as a paramter in the function.

The function uses the PSF parameter as a ndarray, so I tried in this way:

```
from skimage import io
from pylab import array
img = io.imread ("Slice1.tif")
import skimage.restoration as rst
PSF = array (6.7)
img_dbl = rst.richardson_lucy (img, PSF, iterations=10)
```

It shows me this error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`

In CT scans, blurring between two different materials can be linked to a Gaussian PSF. If you have more tips for deblurring (maybe better than RL) just write them.

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Forget about PIL, you are supposed to open the image using `skimage.io.imread` instead. AFAIK PIL uses another image representation that that is not compatible with opencv or skimage.

Comment: Thanks @PauloScardine, I changed it. However, it gives me the same error message.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a gray scale image? Try `img = color.rgb2gray(img)` before calling `richardson_lucy`

Comment: The image is already in grayscale. I tried to convert it anyway, but the result is always the same.

Comment: Are you sure psf can be an unidimensional array? How about something like `np.ones((5, 5)) * 6.7` - running out of guesses.

Comment: The function works but it returns an array made of "nan".

Comment: Aha, some progress - I don't know how you got that 6.7. What if you try with a value like the one from the example in the docs: `np.ones((5, 5)) / 25`?

Comment: Already did it. It doesn't work in this way and there's nothing about it online that helps. I guess that the problem is the PSF parameter. I tried to see if there is a way to establish PSF using python but nothing came on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a similar problem and still researching it. In my case it didn't work if I didn't use `np.uint8` as type. CT data should be 16 bit but only uses the first 12 bits (which are mapped to values between [-1024, 3096]. So I had to rescale my image data to [0-255] before getting anything than black or white out it.

If I understood that correctly, the sum of the PSF should always be 1. What I can guess from your question is that you assume the point spread function to be a gaussian with a meaningful (95% of values?) spread of 6.7 pixels. In that case you would have to model the PSF as a gaussian (that's what I came here for).

You can create one with the method described by @FuzzyDuck in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731818/275195).

```
PSF = gkern(5,2)
```

This would create a gaussian 5x5 kernel with sum 1 using the proposed method by @FuzzyDuck with a sigma of 2. Note that point spread functions could be applied several times so you have to experiment a little bit with the values (or use an algorithm to approximate that).