# How is it possible to create a 2D PSF image for a grayscale image using Python?

Tags: image, image-processing, edge-detection, deconvolution

I need to deconvolve a 2D grayscale image using this function: `skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy`

It requires a PSF image as mandatory parameter.
How is it possible to estimate a 2D PSF image by means of Python?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This website is for programming questions, and your question isn't about programming per se. A helpful keyword to search might be "blind deconvolution". The description of Richardson_Lucy says:

The Richardson–Lucy algorithm, also known as Lucy–Richardson deconvolution, is an iterative procedure for recovering a latent image that has been blurred by a known point spread function.

So you need a known PSF.

Comment: Thanks @Gus. Actually, I computed the PSF using a specific software but it returns a single parameter (in voxels or vx) which represents the edge-blurring lenght between two different materials. I tried to used this parameter (which is roughly 6.5 vx) as an array for the richardson_lucy function but it's not working at all (since it is not a 2D array). I played with the code but it did not work anyway. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585871/psf-point-spread-function-for-an-image-2d
I will also try to apply blind-deconvolution. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: You could in principle fit jointly/blindy for the PSF - active area of research - good luck..... :\